# Appium Touch Actions 'Press' and 'Move To' is not working in iOS chrome app

Tags: appium, touch, appium-ios, xcuitest

I am learning mobile automation and I came across a scenario some thing like this

1. Launch chrome app in iOS
2. Load https://www.google.com
3. Hold/Press and pull down banner web element on the web page which will display some overlay with three options 'New tab, Reload & Close tab' (note: overlay will lost on releasing the banner web element)
4. Tap on the new tab button

So far I have written below script in python

```
def Test(self, driver_provider):
        single_tap = appium.webdriver.common.touch_action.TouchAction(driver_provider.driver)
        element = driver_provider.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('NTPHomeFakeOmniboxAccessibilityID')
        single_tap.tap(element=element).perform()
        element.send_keys('https://www.google.com')
        single_tap.tap(element=driver_provider.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('Go')).perform()
        time.sleep(1)
        #Press banner and pull down will display the over scroll actions
        #Then move to left to tap on the add button
        banner_element = driver_provider.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('banner')
        screen_size = driver_provider.driver.get_window_size()
        height = screen_size.get('height')
        width = screen_size.get('width')
        single_tap.press(banner_element, x=banner_element.size.get(
            'width')/2, y=banner_element.size.get('height')/2).wait(1).move_to(banner_element,
             x=width/2, y=height/2).wait(0.5).move_to(banner_element, x=0, y=height/2).release().perform()
```

for some reason press and move_to actions are not happening and there is no error returned as well, I am not clear what went wrong here. Please share your view on what went wrong thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it's failing to perform press and move to because of wait value is very small. When I use the wait(500) then the press and move to is happening.

single_tap.press(banner_element, x=banner_element.size.get(
'width')/2, y=banner_element.size.get('height')/2).wait(500).move_to(banner_element,
x=width/2, y=height/2).wait(500).move_to(banner_element, x=0, y=height/2).wait(500).release().perform()